# NSUserDefaults object Nil in after performing delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a `UIPickerView` that let the user change a setting for country.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(countries[row], forKey: "SelectedCountry")
    let test = defaults.stringForKey("SelectedCountry")
    delegate?.countryChanged()
}
```

This `test` variable gets the correct value.

However when the delegate method countryChanged is called i get an error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This is the code:

```
func countryChanged() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    countryLabel.text = defaults.stringForKey("SelectedCountry")
}
```

How can the value be nil? It was the correct country just before the delegate method is called, and there is no code inbetween that modifies this value.

Comment: Can you please share your sameple project ?

Comment: You should make sure that `countries[row]` actually contains a `String`.

Comment: func countryChanged() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let text = defaults.stringForKey("SelectedCountry"){
        countryLabel?.text = text
    }
}

Answer (score -1):

You have to persist your modifications to NSUserDefaults:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(countries[row], forKey: "SelectedCountry")
    defaults.synchronize() // must call synchronize here to save your modifications
    let test = defaults.stringForKey("SelectedCountry")
    delegate?.countryChanged()
}
```

Comment: `synchronize` is not needed and does not help to reflect changes within the app.